# Redirecting empty file as input in C

Tags: c, io

I was reading about redirecting an input file to a C program, and came across the following while experimenting with the code and using the empty file "inp":

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=10;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out < inp
10
```

I am unable to understand why scanf() does not halt the program to read input, despite the fact that the file redirected is empty, it skips to the printf() function.

Also, when I modify the code to contain an uninitialized i:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out < inp
0
```

It always prints 0, but by its behaviour above, should it not print the garbage value already present in the uninitialized i?

Comment: Always check return value of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it tells you how conversion went. As for the second question; zero *is* garbage value.

Comment: Your main should be:

`int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: I used another variable to store the return value of scanf and print it, and it prints 0. Does that imply nothing was scanned, and hence it returned NULL?

Comment: Oops, I meant it prints out -1, not 0, which I realized is the EOF character as @Yamakuzure explained from the man page.

Comment: you would get the same behavior if you would run `./a.out` and directly press ctrl+d, which ends the standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf() does not fail on empty input, but simply does nothing. You might want to check the return value as described here:

> man fscanf
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned,
>   which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching
>   failure.
>
> ```
>   The  value  EOF  is  returned if the end of input is reached before either the
>   first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is also returned
>   if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream 
>   (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.
> ```

About the uninitialized i: This is an implicit initialization with 0. Some call it a feature.

However, if you hadn't the scanf() in place, your compiler would have warned you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("%d / %d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation with all warnings enabled:

```
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic test.c -o test
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:11: warning: 'j' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("%d / %d\n", i, j);
           ^
```

Running the program

```
 $ ./test < empty_file
0 / 0
```

You see, even j prints out a zero.

---

I have added another test:

Added after the scanf :

```
    int k = i;
    int l = j;

    printf("%d / %d\n", k, l);
```

Result :

```
 $ ./test < empty_file 
 1115201808 / 0
```

So, while i ran through scanf, j is totally uninitialized.
The result is reproducible at will, k is always random, l is always zero.

Comment: Automatic variables aren't initialized.

Comment: the value 0 is being printed because the printf() is trying to print an integer, so it first initializes its' output values to 0 then examines the bytes in the passed variable.  Each byte in the passed variable is checked to be in the range 0x30 ... 0x39.  if the byte is in the desired range, it is incorporated into the result.  If the byte is not in the desired range, then printf thinks it is done with that variable.  Due to the internal initialization, the printed value is still 0.

Comment: Updated answer with an addition that can't be displayed properly in the comments.

Comment: @user3629249 I think you got the workings of printf reversed! With a %d format it interprets its corresponding argument as integer (whose bytes can have arbitrary values) and *emits* a string of chars with values between  0x30 and 0x39 inclusive, adding the occasional 0x2d for the fun of it. All assuming ASCII, of course.